# Why does this code have a memory leak in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I was told that the following code would result in a memory leak but I'm not certain why

```
object f(void)
    {
    object * o = new object(...);
    return *o;
    }
```

Is it because the object *o is copied before it is returned and the original copy is never deleted because it isn't an automatic variable?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like you understand it correctly. (Side note: "void" isn't needed in the parameter list, that is really old school).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object created by `new` is never `delete`d.

The returned value is a separate object that is copy-constructed from the object pointed to by `o`.

In general, a function `T f(){ /*...*/ return y; }` creates its return value as if by `T{y}` , i.e. constructing a `T` with the argument `y`.